# How should I implement Default Associated Values with Swift Enums?

Tags: swift, enums

Swift question is there a way of having an enum type with one case that can have an associated value.

I have an API that gives me available filters, it's unlikely but possible that the API will add additional filter types. So if the API sends an unknown filter type I want to keep that information associated with the enum.

Below are the different ideas I had about doing this.

My first two tries didn't compile. My third try just feels a bit clunky.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this? Do you think I just shouldn't use an enum for this problem?

```
typealias APIFilterIdentifier = String

/* Does Not Compile */
enum EnumTestAssociatedValeu: APIFilterIdentifier {
    case Unknown(APIFilterIdentifier)
    case Everyone = "everyone"
    case Team = "myteam"
}

/* Does not compile */
enum EnumTestDefaultAssociatedValues: APIFilterIdentifier {
    case Unknown(APIFilterIdentifier)
    case Everyone(APIFilterIdentifier = "everyone")
    case Team(APIFilterIdentifier = "myteam")
}

/* Compiles but is there a better way? */
enum EnumTestWithCustomInit {

    case Unknown(APIFilterIdentifier)
    case Everyone
    case Team

    init(filterIdentifier: APIFilterIdentifier) {
        let everyone: APIFilterIdentifier = EnumTestWithCustomInit.everyoneFilterIdentifier
        let team: APIFilterIdentifier = EnumTestWithCustomInit.teamFilterIdentifier

        switch filterIdentifier {
        case everyone:
            self = .Everyone
        case team:
            self = .Team
        default:
            self = .Unknown(filterIdentifier)
        }
    }

    func asIdentifer() -> APIFilterIdentifier {
        switch self {
        case .Everyone:
            return EnumTestWithCustomInit.everyoneFilterIdentifier
        case .Team:
            return EnumTestWithCustomInit.teamFilterIdentifier
        case .Unknown(let filterIdentifier):
            return filterIdentifier
        }
    }

    private static var everyoneFilterIdentifier: APIFilterIdentifier {
        return "everyone"
    }

    private static var teamFilterIdentifier: APIFilterIdentifier {
        return "myteam"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love if someone would make a better title for this question.

Comment: I have the same question How to implement Default Associated Values with Swift Enums? Did you find an answer? Thanks

Comment: @Mariam It's not possible in Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but would this work for what you want?

```
typealias FilterIdentifier = String

enum DefaultAPIFilters: FilterIdentifier {
    case Everyone = "everyone"
    case Team = "team"
}

enum APIFilters {
    case Default(DefaultAPIFilters)
    case Custom(FilterIdentifier)
}

let everyoneFilter = APIFilters.Default(.Everyone)
let teamFilter = APIFilters.Default(.Team)
let clownFilter = APIFilters.Custom("clowns_only")
```

Comment: How do you get the underlying value back out of this construct? Eg, to get the string for arbitrary manipulation

Comment: I like this method. I think I might make the DefaultAPIFilters an inner enum.

Comment: What is default associated value ?

Answer (score 4):

Extending Nathan Perry's response:

You can add a

```
var underlyingString: String {
  return getUnderlyingString(self) 
}
```

to the enum.  Then define

```
func getUnderlyingString(apiFilter: APIFilters) -> String { 
    switch apiFilter {
    case .Default(let defaultAPIFilter):
        return defaultAPIFilter.rawValue
    case .Custom(let custom):
        return custom
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: [Default value for Enum in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731962/default-value-for-enum-in-swift/61637954#61637954)

I recommend using such an approach

```swift
public enum Result {
    case passed(hint: String)
    case failed(message: String)

    static let passed: Self = .passed(hint: "")
}


let res: Result = Result.passed
```